# Vuetify - label of v-btn (button) overlaps the lateral borders

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In the code below, the button should break the line and increase the its height.
But the text is overlapping the lateral borders (the behavior is reproduced in Codepen link below).

How can it be fixed ?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyMZvb)

```
<v-btn  block outline color="indigo" class="no-text-transform">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec dapibus augue.
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without having used Vuetify before, I can only provide a rudimentary solution (that said, I did look through the docs and couldn't find anything)... It appears the `.v-btn__content` selector that is generated has a `white-space: nowrap` applied to it. So what you can do is add an element to contain your text overriding its parent's style:

```
        <v-btn  block outline color="indigo" class="no-text-transform">
          <span style="white-space: normal;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec dapibus augue.
          </span>
        </v-btn>
```

If that's still too small, you may have to adjust the v-btn height.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    <v-btn
      block
      outline
      >
    <p class="text-wrap" style="width: min-content; margin: auto;">
    Crear Contraseña</p>
    </v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a current Vuetify 2.6.0+ multiline button can be done in a slightly different way.

For some reason you can't override `<span class="v-btn__content">` tag in `default` slot. Unfortunately, your custom content is wrapping in this tag and generated HTML will look like this:

[image: Generated HTML code]

But you can solve your issue this way:

```
<v-btn
  class="btn-multiline"
  width="150"
  height="50"
>
  <span class="text-wrap">Multiline Button Text</span>
</v-btn>

...

<style>
.btn-multiline > span {
  width: 100%
}
</style>
```

So you just need to define custom global `.btn-multiline` class, set full width to `<span class="v-btn__content">` tag and apply internal Vuetify `text-wrap` class that unfolds to `white-space: normal`.

You can try this solution [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/rNdxORm).

Answer (score 0):

here it is without inline styles

```
   <v-btn
     block
     color="blue"
     large
     class="no-text-transform pa-10"
     @click="reviewing"
    >
      <p class="text-wrap ma-auto">
       long text here
      </p>
    </v-btn>
```